# How to do a mathematical operation pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have three columns in pandas dataframe (CSV File), and I need to do a mathematical operation in the third column depending on the other two columns' values how can I do it?
for example, if I have three columns

[image]

I need to change column " C " to a mathematical operation which is: `C = 3*A + B`
So the output must be:

```
C = (3*2) + 4 = 10 ...........
C = (4*2) + 8 = 16
```

[image]

So, how can I do this by a python code?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['C'] = df['A'] * 3 + df['B']
```

Comment: Yes, this is the answer, but don't use an answer to ask a question. Next time ask if it's the answer in the comments under the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["A"] = [2,4]
df["B"] = [4,8]
df["C"] = [10,16]
df["C"] = 3*df["A"] + df["B"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.eval` or DataFrame mathematics operator

```py
df['C'] = df.eval('3 * A + B')

# or

df['C'] = df['A'].mul(3).add(df['B'])
```

```
print(df)

   A  B   C
0  2  4  10
1  4  8  20
```